# Need help getting output from Telnet to array in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, telnet

First I want to apologize for such a silly question but I'm quite new to scripting.

**What I'm attempting to do:**
At my office, I'm attempting to automate the ability to factory reset switches. Its testing equipment for developers not production equipment fyi. I'm trying to dump a list of files from the telnet prompt of the switch into an array and then filter through them to keep our images and delete the rest.

**The constants and variables of the switch:** the switch prompt for this section is =>, the files both do and don't have extensions, folders are outputted as foo\

**My question:** The sub isn't properly issuing the rm command, it works in a test (printing the value) but not in the actual deletion script.

**New Update:**

I know it looks like I abandoned this question, but I didn't! I've been monkeying around with this problem for the last month and I've achieved a major bit of success. I've been able to get my data into my initial array (yes I have 2, more on that in a bit). It will process the array and delete the contents except those I want to keep.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$| = 1;

use Net::Telnet;
use strict;
use CGI;
use warnings;

my $junk;
my $telnet;
my @array;

#establish connection
$telnet = new Net::Telnet (Timeout=> 10,
                           Errmode=> 'return',
                           Port   => '2037');

$telnet->open('trn-13-mrv-con-07');
$telnet->put(chr(13));

#clear out buffered output for array to grab
$junk = $telnet->cmd(string => 'ls', prompt => '/=>/');
#array grabbing
@array = $telnet->cmd(string => 'ls', prompt => '/=>/');

#determining what the values are of the array
foreach my $item (@array) {
   #removing the carriage return
   chomp ($item);
   #if it's a folder, this will shunt the to the sub
   if ($item=~ /\//) {
       subfolders ($item);
       $telnet -> print("rm $item");
   }
   #checks to see if the file is the firmware for the switch
   elsif ($item =~ /btm.swi|secondary.swi/) {
   }
   #deletes the rest
   else {
    $telnet -> print ("rm $item");
    $telnet->put(chr(13));
   }
}

sub subfolders {
 my @subfolder_contents;
 my $subfolder = $_[0];
 my ($file, $sub_junk);

 #attempting to clear out the array
 undef @subfolder_contents;
 #again grabing any cached output so array can do it's work
 $sub_junk = $telnet ->cmd(string => "ls $subfolder", prompt => '/=>/');
 #grabbing files from the folder
 @subfolder_contents = $telnet ->cmd(string => "ls $subfolder", prompt => '/=>/');

 #deleting all files in the subfolder
 foreach $file (@subfolder_contents){
  chomp ($file);
    $telnet-> print ("rm $subfolder$file");
    $telnet->put(chr(13));

 }
};

exit;
```

That all works wonderfully, AND this will work for the folders as well, mostly... It works on the folders if the folder is empty or has just one item in it. When it has 2 or more items in the folder it doesn't issue the command to delete the files in that folder correctly.

Any thoughts would be appreciated. thanks!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer edited due to discussion below**

The problem is indeed the `$t->put(chr(13));`  Sending a `\r` causes the switch to respond with another `=>` prompt which is now in the output. When you issue `cmd`, the `prompt` causes that first line of output to stop the reading.

`empty_buffer` won't work because there's nothing in the input buffer until you call `cmd()`; it isn't a multithreaded application. `cmd()` is doing a write, then reading. That's the first read from the socket that is performed. If you were using `getline` instead at that point you'd have the first line, and the input buffer would contain the rest (or at least most of it depending on how the socket read is done in the library)

If instead of using `cmd` you wrote the command manually using `print` or `put`, then used a loop and `getline()`, you could ignore the first `=>` if you absolutely can't eliminate sending that `\r`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've tried it with the same results. I've probably read that document about 100 times over the last couple of weeks lol.

Comment: THen something isn't right with your `prompt` string, as I note that you say `"I found this out by changing the prompt variable to a file name and it captured and the script dumped all data up to that point"`. I'd test it but I don't have anything on my network that runs a telnet server.

Comment: I thought the same, but it isn't just this one make or model of switch, I get the same result on the other manufacturer pf switches we have. We're using both procurve and H3C switches

Comment: Can you edit your questions and post a copy and paste of a terminal session where you telnet into the switch and then do an `ls` ? You can substitute out the filenames in the output if necessary.

Comment: I've updated my question. I found something slightly interesting. I removed the $t->put(chr(13)); from the script and it magically worked! Ok I know it isn't magic, I assume it something to do with a buffer. I issued the buffer_empty with no luck in improving my script. I would go without the put command but it's a small part in a much larger script so I may need it.

Comment: Oh hell, I didn't even see that, sorry. That makes perfect sense - that's a carriage return `\r` and `put()` does *not* append `\n` so basically when you issue your command it's like sending `\rls\n` ... the switch interprets the `\r` and you get an empty result because it's just another prompt before the output of `ls`

Comment: I bet when you change `prompt` to a filename there's a `=>` in your received output.

Comment: you're correct, there is an => in the output (changed the prompt to a filename to see what data was pulled). like i said, i think it may be that the carriage return is still sitting in the buffer when I issue the cmd which is why it stops. That's why I was thinking that if there was a way to clear the buffer, that would solve the issue.

Comment: The reason `empty_buffer` doesn't work is that the input buffer is empty until you do something that reads (it isn't multithreaded). In your case you're using `cmd` which does a write then reads all the input in one swoop from the buffer rather than something like `readline` which would only give you one line

Comment: Edited answer to reflect discussion, and provide solution.

Answer (score 0):

You likely want to stop capturing the echoed input. Look at cmd_remove_mode in the Net::Telnet docs.

Comment: He is - that's what the `prompt` parameter does.

Comment: That'll yank the prompt -- but not the echoed 'ls' entry. You don't see your input in telnet unless your client does a local echo or the server echoes your input back to the display. I'd guess this is doing the latter. Edit: Ugh, nevermind, I reread the docs -- you're right, Net::Telnet matches the input and trailing prompt internally and should just return the stuff in between.